# How Fix Error " Build Not Recognized ..." when use VS 2019 Command Prompt?

Tags: c, visual-studio, command, development-environment

How Fix Error " Build Not Recognized ..." when use VS 2019 Command Prompt for build "C" File:

[image]

Comment: What is `build`?

Comment: The steps/commands to build a project from the Visual Studios command prompts are [presented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2022).  `build` is not among them, but `MSBuild` is.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to open the powershell from the Visual studio itself.

`Tools -> Command Line -> Developer powershell`.

And try using the command `msbuild` instead of `build`.